# Facing difficulties in Cauchy PDF problem from harvard stats 110 book

Tags: density-function, joint-distribution, cauchy-distribution

[image]

I have two doubts:

1. If X and Y are independent then PDF of X/Y is simply PDF of X(by independence) I don't know where am I interpreting wrong, Please correct me.
2. How X/Y and X/|Y| are identically distributed by the symmetry of the standard Normal distribution Even if so How could we say that P(X/Y <= t) = P(X/|Y| <= t).
   Thank you for your valuable time... :)

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag to this question.

Comment: 1. Yes, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent (as assumed in the first line), $X$ conditional on $Y$ has the same cdf as $X$ unconditional (or marginal). 2. To understand this point, write $X=\text{sign}(X)|X|$ and $Y=\text{sign}(Y)|Y|$ and proceed from the resulting decomposition of $\frac{X}{Y}$.

Comment: Is there some confusion here between the ratio $X/Y$ and the terminology $P(X|Y)$ for the probability of $X$ conditional on $Y$?

Comment: $X/Y$ is the ratio of $X$ and $Y$, so that is your misinterpretation for #1.

Comment: **Not exactly as advertised:** First, it's Example 7.1.25. Second, it's not a problem but an example for which the proof is given. Third, full statement in text says that $T=X/Y$ (no conditioning) for indep $X,Y$ with caveat that value of $T$ for event $\{Y=0\}$ of probability $0$ needs an arbitrary definition.

Comment: Thank You @StubbornAtom and EdM I was misinterpreting for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

One way of understanding they are not independent is to take a large value of $X$ say $2$ and a small value of $Y$ say $.1$ this will result in the fatter tails than the original $X$ distribution. There will be quite a few values close to zero, so this situation will be fairly common.

For the second part, you could consider negative and positive $t$ separately. Because of symmetry of each of the two constituent normal distributions there are equal chances of the result being positive or negative. Thus you can just consider whether one of the numerator or denominator is positive or negative, and in the text they have chosen $Y$ which looks slightly more elegant.